# javascript - set first ul class

Tags: conditionaltagsupport

My problem is, in the first result, the first ul tag have main-menu classes (), but in the second result, the classes replaced by child classes, as defined in the script.

I expect the script to only set child classes for ul tag that converted from "dashed" li, and not affect my first ul tag that previously have had main-menu classes. I expect result like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adapt your code you can just check your `level` when you create a new `<ul>`. If the `level` is zero use the original class of existing `<ul>` and if not set class to `"child"`

```
/* store initial main class */
var mainClass=$('#main-navigation .widget ul:first').attr('class'); 

$('#main-navigation .widget li').each(function () {

    ......./* code removed for clarity */

         if (level > dd_level) {
             var ulClass = level === 0 ? mainClass : 'child';
             dd_html += '<ul class="' + ulClass + '">';
         }

    ....../* code removed for clarity */

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/obtnyuL9/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: can we add any class to `li` that have a `ul` as child? e.g. `<li class="have-child">`

I forget to ask this in my question

Comment: simple way using `:has` selector and addClass()